# Keep calling a function on mouseDown in ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events, ember-data

I need to keep calling a function on `mousedown` and I have following code:

```
<button id="zoomin" type="button" {{action "zoomIn" on="mouseDown" target="view" }} class="btn">
    <i class="icon-zoom-in"></i>
</button>
```

But it is only called when mouse is down and I want it to be called repeatedly until mouse is up.

Is there any solution other than `timer`?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using `mousemove` instead of `mousedown`. This will call your function repeatedly whenever the mouse moves, without having to set up a timer. Of course, this would not work if you want the function to be called periodically even when the mouse is stationary.

If you do use `mousemove`, you'll have to deal with lots of events involving uninterestingly small moves. So you will probably want to "debounce" the events, to filter out very small moves and very frequent events, along the following lines:

```
const DELTA = 5;         // only report moves of greater than five pixels
const DELTA_TIME = 100;  // only report moves every 100ms
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    // Remember previous coordinates and time.
    lastX: null,
    lastY: null,
    lastTime: null,

    // Set up `this.mousemove` so it's bound property.
    bind() { this.mousemove = this.mousemove.bind(this); }.on('init'),

    // Set up and tear down event listeners.
    mousedown() { this.get('element').addEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove); },
    mouseup()   { this.get('element').removeEventListener('mousemove', this.mousemove); },

    mousemove(event) {
        var { screenX, screenY } = event;
        var { lastX, lastY, lastTime } = this.getProperties('lastX', 'lastY', 'lastTime');
        var now = +new Date();

        if (Math.abs(screenX - lastX) < DELTA && Math.abs(screenY - lastY)) < DELTA ||
            now - lastTime < DELTA_TIME) return;
        this.setProperties({ lastX: screenX, lastY: screenY, lastTime: now });
        this.handleMouseMove(event);
    }
});
```

If you do want to call your function repeatedly even when the mouse has not moved, then yes, you need a timer. For better interoperability with the Ember run loop, you are better off using `Ember.run` than `setTimeout` or `setInterval`. Ember does not provide the equivalent of `setInterval`, so you will have to set up the timer again and again, as in

```
const INTERVAL = 500;

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    timer: false,

    mousedown(event) { this.startTimer(); },
    mouseup(event)   { this.stopTimer(); },

    startTimer()     { 
        this.set('timer', true); 
        Ember.run.next(this, this.tick, INTERVAL); },

    stopTimer()      { this.set('timer', false); },

    tick             { 
        // process tick
        if (!this.get('timer')) return;
        this.startTimer();      // set up timer again
    }

});
```

This needs tuning and debugging, but I hope you get the idea.